# post form to facebook event wall

Tags: php, facebook, forms

I have a facebook event, and i want to send the members a form that i created and hosted on my website, asking them what days they are available to meet. I want is so that when they hit submit it will post the information from the form to the event wall.

I have never done anything with facebook, and the examples i found were to post on your own wall not an event wall.

as of now the form is handled by a php script which just emails me the result.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Facebook for Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/)

This is more complex than it seems.

1)  Register your website that houses the form as a facebook app.
2)  Add php code or javascript code to request permission to post on behalf of your users.
3)  On submit, send a message to facebook to post on the event wall.

The message would follow the format found [here](https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/feed?access_token=2227470867%7C2.JA9i7LlS7ohM4ITFYY_p8g__.3600.1304809200.0-39116797%7C2wu1wbVoQ8F0MoTJtCgkfJFZoh0).
[Details of Event API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)

The url of the event wall would be https://graph.facebook.com/{event}/feed.